# How to make rendering of a component wait until we get the data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on adding create option to my fronted react app, As I first want to test the fronted's working , I used localStorage for storing my data. Based on the length of data, that I receive from the localStorage I will render two different components (if the length is zero, then one else the other) . I am using useEffect() hook to get the data and to prevent the error "localStorage is not defined". But, the hook is slow and it takes around 5/6 seconds to actually render the second component if I add some data value into the localStorage and by default the code is rendering just the first component even if the length of the data in the localStorage is non-zero.

The code part:

```
export default function Onboard() {
  const [dataValues, setdataValues] = useState('');
  const [redFlag, setredFlag] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    let val;
    val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataValues') || '[]') || [];
    setdataValues(val);
    let flag;
    flag = dataValues.length;
    setredFlag(flag);
  }, []);
  const [popup, setpopup] = useState(false);
  const [SelectedAccess, setSelectedAccess] = useState('All');
  return (
    <div>
        {redFlag == 0 ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
    </div>
   )}
```

This is just a snippet of the code. By default the code is rendering Component1 even if the localStorage has values stored in it and it takes a long delay to render Component2. Any help regarding this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you can update the useEffect to set the redFlag state based on the val.length directly instead of relying on dataValues.length.

```
export default function Onboard() {
  const [dataValues, setdataValues] = useState([]);
  const [redFlag, setredFlag] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let val;
    try {
      val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataValues')) || [];
    } catch (error) {
      val = [];
    }
    setdataValues(val);
    setredFlag(val.length);
  }, []);

  const [popup, setpopup] = useState(false);
  const [SelectedAccess, setSelectedAccess] = useState('All');

  return (
    <div>
      {redFlag === 0 ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one I hope this will solve your problem. Check and comment...

```
export default function Onboard() {
    const [dataValues, setdataValues] = useState("");

    let val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DataValues"));

    useEffect(() => {
        setdataValues(val);
    }, [val]);
    const [popup, setpopup] = useState(false);
    const [SelectedAccess, setSelectedAccess] = useState("All");
    return <div>{dataValues ? <Component2 /> : <Component1 />}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if redflag length is greater than zero then show the component otherwise not.

```js
export default function Onboard() {
  const [dataValues, setdataValues] = useState('');
  const [redFlag, setredFlag] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    let val;
    val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataValues') || '[]') || [];
    setdataValues(val);
    let flag;
    flag = dataValues.length;
    setredFlag(flag);
  }, []);
  const [popup, setpopup] = useState(false);
  const [SelectedAccess, setSelectedAccess] = useState('All');
  return (
    <div>
        {redFlag > 0 ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
    </div>
   )}
```

Comment: but bro I need both of these components for render, one if it doesnt contain the data else the other. One is like for the new users and the other is for users who are already using the website

Comment: just replace null with other component which you want to show when redflag is 0.